# Trouble with switching different URL's in order to switch a GIF animation

Tags: java, swing, url, animated-gif

I'm creating a StreetFighter kind of game, and I'm having trouble changing the GIF animations when the game is won. I changed the URL when the JProgressBar is equal to 0, but it does nothing. If anyone can help fix this problem, thanks in advance.

```
  public class Player1 {

static JButton playerPunch = new JButton("Punch");
 static JButton playerKick = new JButton("Kick");
 static JButton playerSpecial = new JButton("Special Attack");
static JButton playerNothing = new JButton("Do Nothing");
public static void runAll(){
    PlayerPunch();
    PlayerKick();
    PlayerSpecial();
    PlayerNothing();
    endGame();

}
public static void endGame(){
    if(HealthBar.PlayerHealth.getValue() == 0){

    }
    if(HealthBar.EnemyHealth.getValue() == 0){
        Game.gifString = ("http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lgpely0wDJ1qg8wsi.gif");
    }
}
```

and here's the 2nd part of another class including the URL itself.

```
   static String gifString = new String("http://cdn.gifbay.com/2012/10/mortal_kombat_prom-3939.gif");
static JPanel playerPanel = new JPanel();
static JButton start = new JButton("Start");
static JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
static JPanel menu = new Menu();
static JPanel bg = new JPanel();
static int state = 0;
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
    final JPanel masterPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    final JFrame f = new JFrame("Mortal Kombat Game");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
URL url = new URL(gifString);
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
final JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
final JLabel title = new JLabel("Mortal Kombat Game");
f.pack();

f.setVisible(true);
f.setSize(498,400);
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

Comment: 1. Your use of `static` is just wrong. 2. Just switching an URL is not going to do much for you. 3. Obtaining an image from an URL is a long running task which should not be done. Instead obtain all the images you need during application launch and store the images where you can access them later. Then just switch them with a `JLabel.setIcon` or something

Comment: I see, I'm going to try out setIcon. Can you please explain to me what do you mean when I used static wrong?

Comment: You need to learn the difference between instance and static variables and when to use them. All your components should be instance components and not static. The only reason you probably feel you need them is because 1. you're doing too much on the `main` method which is `static` and requires accessed objects to also be static 2. Same with your other method. That just means you have a problem with your design. Go through some of the [Swing Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) to see good practices an class design

Comment: I see, thanks for the help will check out the tutorial.

Comment: Actually, I see the problem. I added a few lines of coding which setsEnable(false) on my jbuttons after you lose, however it doesn't affect the program at all. I also changed the URL method and got the GIF from a stored location on my computer btw.

Comment: I still am having trouble with this problem :/ does anyone know how to fix it? Whatever I put in the if statements of the endGame method doesn't work.

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see where you're going wrong